# Invoking Async Task via Reflection

Tags: c#, task

I need to do the following:

1. I have a couple of async methods in the following form:

   `async Task<string> MethodName(args) {}`
2. I need to invoke any of these methods via reflection - I do this:

   `Task<string> task = Invoke(instanceContainingThisMethod, args);`

   I then need to call either OnSuccess or OnFailure functions, provided the task returned an exception or not. How can I do this? Should I use ContinueWith?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Please improve the title. It says absolutely nothing about the question.

Answer (score 0):

Treat this task like any other task. There's no difference between:

```
Task t = MethodName(...);
```

and

```
Task t = Invoke(instanceContainingThisMethod, args);
```

from the point of view of the caller. Just a different "calling convention".

You can `await` it, for example. `await` works on Tasks (more precisely, awaitables), not on method calls.